# Как поменять цвет кнопки после её нажатия, а после второго щелчка вернуть исходный цвет ? Java, Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Не могли бы Вы подсказать как поменять цвет кнопки после её нажатия, а после второго щелчка вернуть исходный цвет. Я новичок в java, ещё разбираюсь.
Работаю через Netbeans, jframe, всё через конструктор. Получилось сделать так чтобы кнопка перекрашивалась при щелчке в зелёный, а вот при втором щелчке не знаю как вернуть исходный цвет или любой другой.
Вот так я прописал чтобы кнопка перекрашивалась:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 0));
    }
```

Также прикреплю скриншот с результатом:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4BJL.png

Можете помочь ?

Comment: Перед перекрашиванием надо сохранить текущий цвет, чтобы потом его восстановить

Comment: У меня тот же вопрос можете помоч?